# Terminator does not start after updating

Tags: terminator

I use terminator all the time and would like to get it working again. The issue may be with updating my system. I recently updated things to use a wacom tablet and installed some drivers.

I read other threads about the python version not being correct, but that does not seem to be the case. The python version from `which python` returns python version 2.7.12.

The global config file is also not the problem because I created one and put it in the location `~/.config/terminator/config`.

Already tried purge and reinstall many times. I did add the ppa to the repository

When I start terminator from terminal this is the error:

```
:~/.config/terminator$ terminator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 122, in <module>
    TERMINATOR.create_layout(OPTIONS.layout)
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py", line 311, in create_layout
    window, terminal = self.new_window()
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py", line 234, in new_window
    terminal = maker.make('Terminal')
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/factory.py", line 94, in make
    output = func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/factory.py", line 106, in make_terminal
    return(terminal.Terminal())
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminal.py", line 147, in __init__
    self.update_url_matches()
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminal.py", line 273, in update_url_matches
    reg = Vte.Regex.new_for_match(re, len(re), self.regex_flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 139, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Vte' object has no attribute 'Regex'
```

Comment: My guess is you're using 16.04; however it's better if we are told rather than having to guess (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python)  What do you get for `python -V; python3 -V` (I gather from your info you'll get 2.7.12 for the first, but please re-try) and confirm your release.

Comment: Release is ubuntu 16.04, respectively those two commands gave python 2.7.12, python 3.5.2

Comment: I installed an old version and compiled it from the source, it opens as normal, but I no longer have an icon for it. Is there a simple way to make one? Can this be done using a desktop launcher?

Comment: as i have answered in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247914/terminator-permission-denied-for-sudo/#1319065, this new & maintained repo worked for me on 20.04.2 LTS: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are pulling off the new & maintained repo:
https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator

as i have answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247914/terminator-permission-denied-for-sudo/#1319065), snap binary is also broken currently, but this worked for me on 20.04.2 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator
sudo apt update
sudo apt install terminator
```