# terminator: permission denied for sudo

Tags: sudo, 20.04, terminator

I updated to Ubuntu 20.04. When I use the default terminal, everything is fine. But if try to use terminator, I cannot use `sudo`. I get `permission denied`. Again, only when using terminator.

How can I `sudo` from the terminator? I really would like to continue to use a terminator.

**Edit:** I just also noted that it cannot find `make` either. I guess it's all messed up. I'll try to uninstall it and install again I guess.

Comment: [20.04.2] also broken same way on 1.9.1 via snap on beta channel:
sudo snap install gnome-terminator --beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 when downloading Terminator from Ubuntu Software.

Installing Terminator from terminal with `apt install terminator` resolved this issue.

Comment: I have font/display probmems -- When I looked, the ["Latest Version: DELETED" focal 20.04](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/universe/proposed/terminator).

Answer (score 1):

on 20.04.2 LTS, i have gotten rid of my broken snap (v1.9.1) with:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-terminator
```

but if you haven't installed it via snap, you can uninstall it with:

```
sudo apt --purge remove terminator
```

then you have 2 OPTIONS (both of which i tested and work):

- v2.0.1

via NEW repo via NEW and actively maintaining team: https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator
sudo apt update
sudo apt install terminator
```

- or v0.98

via OLD classic route:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator
sudo apt update
sudo apt install terminator
```

however you will get error when doing:

```
sudo apt update
```

something like this (error number and IP will be different):

```
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

because Terminator's repo has been stale for while now :( [https://launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

so i replaced `focal` with `xenial` (last one supported when you click on 'Technical details about this PPA' and then on drop-down 'Choose your Ubuntu version'), like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-terminator-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
```

amended (my top) line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal main
```

to:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

then save and do again:

```
sudo apt update
```

and error is gone.