# User can sudo from terminal but not when logged into gnome

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, sudo

I just finished re-installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Lattitude E-6420 and logged in to re-install the apps I need. When trying to run `sudo apt install <app>`, I see the following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

I see the same when running `sudo ls /etc`. Permissions on `/usr/bin/sudo` are:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 149080 Oct 10  2019 /usr/bin/sudo
```

and I am in adm and sudo groups. What makes this even more odd is that when I log out from GNOME, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or from the log-in screen and log into the terminal, I can now use `sudo` as that same user. Any ideas what could be happening or even better, how to fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /etc/sudoers`? Are you able to use `pkexec`?

Comment: -r--r----- 1 root root 755 Jan 17 2018 /etc/sudoers. Interestingly, when I try to run pkexec when I'm logged into gnome I get a not found error...but when I log in from the terminal I can run it. permissions on pkexec (usr/bin) are: -rwsr-xr-x and it is owned by root:root

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: <typing this out manually since I can't see it on the laptop>
Defaults env_reset
Defaults mail_badpass
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

<<there are no additional users>>

Comment: UNREAL...I found the answer here: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247914/terminator-permission-denied-for-sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247914/terminator-permission-denied-for-sudo) I've used Terminator for years without issue but it just didn't work today. UGH!